# tf.train.get.global_step error during Tensorflow classification example

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, scikit-learn, classification

I am following Siraj Raval's YouTube video for building a simple classifier for the iris flower data set. The video was dated May of 2016 so I am sure that there are some areas of Tensorflow that have been updated. I am getting an error that says "please switch to tf.train.get.global_step. I am working off of the older dated Tensorflow library and I have tried figuring out the new one by researching feature_columns. I thought this would fix it but the error persists. Any help is greatly appreciated and any advice on becoming an educated Tensorflow user is openly welcome.

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

feature_columns = skflow.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)

classifier = skflow.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, n_classes=3)

classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)


score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

And here is the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:float64 is not supported by many models, consider casting to float32.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\isaia\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8be6vyhq
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/isaia/PycharmProjects/untitled5/ml.py:10: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with x is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:/Users/isaia/PycharmProjects/untitled5/ml.py:10: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with y is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
WARNING:tensorflow:float64 is not supported by many models, consider casting to float32.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\isaia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\linear.py:173: get_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_global_step
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This estimator [is basically deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearClassifier#fit) and can be removed from tensorflow in the next releases (and you get several warnings about it), you should use [`tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier). Its API is slightly different, but the idea is still the same. Here's the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# The classifier
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[4])]
classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                           n_classes=3)

# Training
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": iris.data},
                                                    y=iris.target,
                                                    num_epochs=50,
                                                    shuffle=True)
classifier.train(train_input_fn)

# Testing
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": iris.data},
                                                   num_epochs=1,
                                                   shuffle=False)
predictions = classifier.predict(test_input_fn)
predicted_classes = [p["classes"].astype(np.float)[0] for p in predictions]

score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, predicted_classes)
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of training steps in the **classifier.fit** method in your code. I have edited your code and given comments where its necessary.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

feature_columns = skflow.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)

classifier = skflow.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target,steps=10) #Define the Number of traning steps here
results = classifier.predict(x=iris.data, as_iterable=False) #Set as_iterable=False to get an 1-D array for metrics.accuracy_score

score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, results)

print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Moreover, in order to get a 1-D array as class predictions, you may need to set **as_iterable=False** in the **classifier.predict** method.

Hope this helps.